# Does the while loop and the 'and' logical operator have a limit to the int range they can print out?

Tags: python, while-loop, comparison

I am writing a python script that calculates the capacity of eggs an incubator can carry based on the number of trays in it. Each tray can carry 88 eggs and there are three categories to the incubators. Small, medium and large. the small and medium ranges print out the output well but when it comes to the large sizes, it only prints out a blank area. Where should i fix my code to get the large sizes printed out too?

I have tried calculating using only the range starting from the minimum size a large incubator should carry but it still gives me the same problem. I have tried switching the medium size calculation code with values to calculate the large sizes but it still disappears.

```
tray_number = 2
tray_cap = 88

'small range'
small_min_cap = 176
small_max_cap = 704

'medium range'
medium_min_cap = 880
medium_max_cap = 5000

'large range'
large_min_cap = 5704
large_max_cap = 10000

capacity_increase = tray_cap*2
capacity = 0
total_cap = capacity + capacity_increase

print('Incubator calculations :\n')

'Calculations of the small capacity range'
print('SMALL CAPACITY:')
while small_max_cap >= total_cap >= small_min_cap:
    print('a small incubator with ' + str(tray_number) + ' trays has a total capacity of = ' + str(total_cap))
    total_cap += capacity_increase
    tray_number += 2
print('\n')

'Calculations of the medium capacity range increasing by 2 trays each'
print('MEDIUM CAPACITY:')
while medium_max_cap >= total_cap >= medium_min_cap:
    print('a medium incubator with ' + str(tray_number) + ' trays has a total capacity of = ' + str(total_cap))
    total_cap += capacity_increase
    tray_number += 2
print('\n')

'Calculations of the large capacity range increasing by 2 trays each'
print('LARGE CAPACITY:')
while large_max_cap >= total_cap >= large_min_cap:
    print('a large incubator with ' + str(tray_number) + ' trays has a total capacity of = ' + str(total_cap))
    total_cap += capacity_increase
    tray_number += 2
print('\n')
```

i expect that after the  'LARGE CAPACITY' header, a list like the ones of the small and medium capacity ranges to show also for the large one.

what i am  getting as my output is this:

```
Incubator calculations :

SMALL CAPACITY:
a small incubator with 2 trays has a total capacity of = 176
a small incubator with 4 trays has a total capacity of = 352
a small incubator with 6 trays has a total capacity of = 528
a small incubator with 8 trays has a total capacity of = 704


MEDIUM CAPACITY:
a medium incubator with 10 trays has a total capacity of = 880
a medium incubator with 12 trays has a total capacity of = 1056
a medium incubator with 14 trays has a total capacity of = 1232
a medium incubator with 16 trays has a total capacity of = 1408
a medium incubator with 18 trays has a total capacity of = 1584
a medium incubator with 20 trays has a total capacity of = 1760
a medium incubator with 22 trays has a total capacity of = 1936
a medium incubator with 24 trays has a total capacity of = 2112
a medium incubator with 26 trays has a total capacity of = 2288
a medium incubator with 28 trays has a total capacity of = 2464
a medium incubator with 30 trays has a total capacity of = 2640
a medium incubator with 32 trays has a total capacity of = 2816
a medium incubator with 34 trays has a total capacity of = 2992
a medium incubator with 36 trays has a total capacity of = 3168
a medium incubator with 38 trays has a total capacity of = 3344
a medium incubator with 40 trays has a total capacity of = 3520
a medium incubator with 42 trays has a total capacity of = 3696
a medium incubator with 44 trays has a total capacity of = 3872
a medium incubator with 46 trays has a total capacity of = 4048
a medium incubator with 48 trays has a total capacity of = 4224
a medium incubator with 50 trays has a total capacity of = 4400
a medium incubator with 52 trays has a total capacity of = 4576
a medium incubator with 54 trays has a total capacity of = 4752
a medium incubator with 56 trays has a total capacity of = 4928


LARGE CAPACITY:



Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `print(large_max_cap, total_cap, large_min_cap) # => 10000 5104 5704` so the final loop never executes because 5104 < 5704. The numbers are nowhere near Python's maximum size, so that's not the problem. What are you expecting to happen here?

Comment: thank you for your help. i was under the assumption that total_cap will be reset to 0 after every loop. i have realized where i made the mistake and didn't factor in that the values keep on adding from the previous ones

Comment: Glad it worked out. You might want to put this code in a function to avoid having to type it out three times and avoid state carrying from one to the next, which can be confusing. Also, the stray strings might be better as actual comments using `# comment` syntax.